# Send message to specific user

Tags: c#, angularjs, signalr

I'm trying to send the user that connects a welcome message, but something like this won't work:

```
    public void Connected(string name)
    {
        Clients.this.newMessage("Hello world!"); //Welcome message to current user

        Clients.All.userConnected(name); //Joined message to everyone
    }
```

I know it's not a lot of information I give you, but I don't know what you need.
(My front end is with angularJs, that might be useful)

Comment: You need to debug where you have the problem....
Debug debug debug...

Comment: @joreldraw There is not really a problem, so debugging is not the solution. It's just not doing what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name);

        Clients.Group(name).newMessage("Hello world!"); //Welcome message to current user

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```